# Adjusting flow map styles in QGIS 2

Tags: style, cartography, qgis-2, flow-map

In one project, I am trying to adopt marvellous styles for flow maps created by @underdark.

At this moment I have the following output

[image: Flow_map]

Shapefile was created with the usage of [Flow maps (Oursins)](https://github.com/LCacheux68224/Oursins) Plugin.

Lines have different directions, i.e. the starting point of first is the ending point of the second and vice versa. So basically the table includes lines with both directions but without any description of those directions.

[image: Sample_of_AT]

---

However, I faced several issues

**1. Varying buffers' sizes**

Buffers around points shall inherit parameters from a different layer, i.e. they are not the same size.

How to make them respond to the size of the circles' radiuses? Is there any kind of scaling factor, so to make my buffers *"dynamic"*?

```py
difference(
  difference(
    $geometry,
    buffer(start_point($geometry), 500)
  ),
  buffer(end_point($geometry), 500)
)
```

Maybe I to apply `layer_property()` or `dbvaluebyid()` or `represent_value()` if I want to extract the dynamic value from a different layer?

I know that the buffer values in the expression above only produce appropriate results for line datasets which use a CRS in meters and will have to be adjusted for other units.

**2. Proper allocation of arrows**

I am using an expression for `Arrow type > Plain`

```sql
CASE
    WHEN x(start_point($geometry)) - x(end_point($geometry)) < 0 THEN 1
    ELSE 2
END
```

but still, I can not properly allocate orange halves of Arrows on the opposite side of blues.

**3. The width of the arrows**

I want to adjust the line width accordingly to the values of a field `"FLUX"`. For that reason, I am using an expression for `Arrow width`.

```sql
scale_linear("FLUX",0,10,0.1,3) * CASE WHEN  "FLUX" > 1000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

How shall I handle those issues?

---

My desired output should look like this, curved lines can be ignored.

[image: Desired_output]

---

**References:**

- [QGIS-resource-collections](https://github.com/anitagraser/QGIS-resource-collections)
- [Seeking QGIS geometry generator manual?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222064/seeking-qgis-geometry-generator-manual)
- [Details of good flow maps](https://anitagraser.com/2016/12/18/details-of-good-flow-maps/)
- [New style: flow map arrows](https://anitagraser.com/2016/12/30/new-style-flow-map-arrows/)
- [Representing network flows?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/778/representing-network-flows)
- [Selecting features with same geometry in one shapefile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/304352/selecting-features-with-same-geometry-in-one-shapefile)

Comment: Thinking loud: Could you half the width of your arrows and then place them on one or the other side of your line? Like `CASE WHEN x(start_point($geometry)) - x(end_point($geometry)) < 0 THEN -0.5 ELSE 0.5 END` entered as "offset"-value (or use `1` instead of `0.5`). Or is that not desirable for your intended style?

Comment: Unfortunately, not that much, I have to have a good looking map for further investigations and research. Your idea makes sense, but not what I dream about.

Comment: What's wrong with the direction and width of the arrows? It would help if you added an image of what you want the arrows to look like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. Varying buffers' sizes**

First of all Switch to *Map Unit*.

With suggestions from @Albert, I have joined buffer values from a layer for `start_point` and `end_point` points and moreover, I edited the circles and visualized them as Simple marker. Using the formula `scale_linear("Value", minimum("Value"), maximum("Value"), 1, 6)`

The required buffer size obeyed uses a scaling factor of `2`, notice the difference in `range_min, range_max` between two functions.

```py
difference(
    difference($geometry,
        buffer(start_point($geometry),
        CASE
          WHEN "From_Value" IS NOT NULL THEN scale_linear("From_Value", minimum("From_Value"), maximum("From_Value"), 2, 12)
          ELSE 0
        END
        )
    ),
    buffer(end_point($geometry),
    CASE
      WHEN "To_Value" IS NOT NULL THEN scale_linear("To_Value", minimum("To_Value"), maximum("To_Value"), 2, 12)
      ELSE 0
    END)
)
```

Do not forget to double check values of `start_point()`, `end_point()` and `min&max`, they have to be the same between point and polyline layers.

**2. Proper allocation of arrows**

The correct expression

```sql
CASE
  WHEN x(start_point($geometry)) - x(end_point($geometry)) < 0 THEN 2
  WHEN x(start_point($geometry)) - x(end_point($geometry)) > 0 THEN NULL
  ELSE 1
END
```

The output will look like

[image: Arrows_locations]

Another solution can be achieved with the creation of two layers via a `'Virtual Layer'` and then adjusting the styles manually. However, it is a bit time-consuming approach.

Layer 1 (Left/Exterior half):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM flow_map_sample
WHERE x(ST_StartPoint(geometry)) - x(ST_EndPoint(geometry)) < 0
```

Layer 2 (Right/Exterior half):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM flow_map_sample
WHERE x(ST_StartPoint(geometry)) - x(ST_EndPoint(geometry)) > 0
```

**3. The width of the arrows**

I needed to use:

```sql
scale_linear("FLUX", minimum("FLUX"), maximum("FLUX"), 0.1, 3) *
  CASE
    WHEN "FLUX" > 1000 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END
```

Answer (score 4):

**1. Varying buffers size**

I would recommend you to join the attributes of both layers instead of fetching layer properties. These are the expressions I used in [this example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222064/seeking-qgis-geometry-generator-manual):

Point layer size:

```py
scale_exp("attributeBuffer", minTotalFlux, maxTotalFlux, @min, @max, exponent)
```

Geometry generator of line layer:

```py
difference(
  difference($geometry,
  buffer(start_point($geometry), scale_exp("attributeBufferStart", minTotalFlux, maxTotalFlux, (@min/2), (@max/2), exponent),
  buffer(end_point($geometry), scale_exp("attributeBufferEnd", minTotalFlux, maxTotalFlux, (@min/2), (@max/2), exponent)
  )
)
```

Where `"attributeFromStart"` and `"attributeFromEnd"` are the values used to buffer the points. You need to use map units and not millimetres in your point since the geometry generator of lines will be working with map units.
`@project_variables` were used to easily change sizes in the project properties without having to enter the changes in each layer.

**2. Proper allocation of arrows**

I think your problem is switching your direction in two layers. Your line geometries have opposite directions already so both should be going to the same side. It is like cars, you stick to one side of the road, otherwise, both ways would end up using the same lane.

Comment: I think you have edited the question while I was answering. Anyway, the `difference()` function is to make your line start and end according to your point values (same you use to buffer the point layer). For this, I joined the values in my line features. I also had some @project_variables so I could easily adjust all sizes (point buffers and line start/ends) easily.

Comment: These are project variables, you can put the min/max values of the field. I entered them as variables so I could just change them from the project properties easily without having to enter every layer. The 1.2 exponent could also be another project variable.

Comment: What do you mean by adjusting? Map units depend on the coordinate system you use. In your case I recommend you to use map units and a projected coordinate system

Comment: I have edited the answer to better explain how to adjust the lines and buffers

Comment: You can also calculate a new field in your point with the desired size, join this new attribute in lines and forget about case or scale_ expressions. However, it will be more difficult to make changes if you don't like the size since you will need to recalculate the fields.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90561/discussion-between-albert-and-taras).