# Adjusting buffer between arrows and both begin and end points separately

Tags: qgis, style, cartography, virtual-layer, flow-map

I'm currently making a map of the Netherlands in which the flow of student migrations upon or shortly after their graduation is depicted. Here's what I've made so far:

[image]

I'm getting a bit more pleased with the result, but I'm not quite there yet. Something I'd like to adjust in particular is the buffering space of the arrows. In particular, I'd like to change the buffering between the end points of the arrows and their destinations *only*.

So for the the starting points, I'd like to keep everything the same. I'm okay with how it looks at the Southernmost arrow, for instance:

[image]

When we look the the destinations of the arrows, however, things get more messy. They're lumped together at the exact same location:

[image]

In order to create some more space between the arrows at the end points, I tried adjusting the I've found in this blog [post](https://anitagraser.com/2019/05/04/flow-maps-in-qgis-no-plugins-needed/) by Anita Graser. The code is used in the Geometry Generator of the virtual layer of the arrows:

```py
difference(
    difference(
        make_line(start_point($geometry), centroid(offset_curve($geometry, length($geometry)/(-5 + log(3.5,intensity)/1.9))), end_point($geometry)),
        buffer(start_point($geometry), 0.01)
        ),
    buffer(end_point($geometry),0.5)
    )
```

Adjusting the values of the buffer at the start_point and end_point does not seem to have any effect on the actual buffering space of the arrows on the map, though. So my **question** is: how to change the buffering space between the arrowheads and their destination locations to a suitable value?

Comment: Check my question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/314057

Comment: @Taras Thank you. I figured out the problem: apparently the buffering is in meters, so I couldn't see the changes when I made small adjustments. Had to change it to 5000 (quite a leap from 0.01 imho) to see any differences on the map.